# Regexp matching of "a*" in expect

Tags: regex, expect

I have following `expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn echo "aabab"
expect -re "a*" {
    puts "<$expect_out(0,string)>"
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./re.exp 
spawn echo aabab
<>
```

I expected the regex to be greedy and match `aa`, but an empty string was matched instead.

Isn't `expect`'s matching be greedy by default?  How can I get my desired match of `aa`?

I am running expect-5.45-18.fc22.x86_64 from Fedora 22 (Debian 8.2 is the same).

Comment: Organize your codes so we can understand better. Which string are we matching? What is your expected outcome? What is the actual outcome?

Comment: @frosty - The string being matched to is the `aabab` from the `echo` process that was spawned.  The expected outcome was that the regular expression would be "greedy" and matched `aa`, not an empty string.

Comment: Although regular expressions are greedy, Expect stops processing input as soon as it finds a match, it doesn't keep going to see if it contains a longer match as well.

Comment: @Barmar - Isn't that the *exact opposite* of greedy though?

Comment: The point is that Expect isn't matching the regexp against the entire input. It matches it incrementally.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Is his regex "a*"? That matches 0 or more a's. That's why it also matches an empty string. If he wants at least 1 a, he should use "a+", which means 1 or more a's. If he wants exactly 2 a's, he should use "a{2}", which would match exactly 2 a's.

Comment: @Barmar - I believe you are right, there's no need for expect to match beyond empty string here. Thank you.